# how do i launch an activity from a seperate package via intent

Tags: android

I have two packages in my app com.first.main and com.second.activity2. I have tried this a few times but I keep getting class not found even though I have added these files to my manifest.

1.How do I launch the activity  in the second package from the first. 
 2. If I have to add a second activity to the first package eg com.first.secondactivity , do I need to do anything different to launch it from the com.first.main activity?

Am really stuck on the this for last few hours so would appreciate some help

Thanks

Comment: And the code you're using to send the Intent, too. It's probably some really trivial but unintuitive thing like forgetting to declare the activities as exported --- I've been here many times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably not stating the full package name in the manifest and thus the activity is expected to be in your main package.
You should state the full package name in the Activity declaration. e.g.:

```
<activity android:name="com.second.activity2.Activity"/>
```

And not just

```
<activity android:name=".Activity"/>
```

Comment: Thanks- that was exactly the problem.  Also just a mention that if you are using the Class.forName construct to load dynamically, you also need to to use the full package+name to get it to work properly.  Nice One thanks!